# Приложение падает с ошибкой kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException lateinit property presenter has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger2

Полный стек ошибок

```
Fatal Exception: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException
lateinit property presenter has not been initialized
registration.withdocument.RegistrationWithDocumentFragment.createValidateWatcher + 88 (RegistrationWithDocumentFragment.kt:88)
registration.withdocument.RegistrationWithDocumentFragment.onViewCreated + 46 (RegistrationWithDocumentFragment.kt:46)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 1471 (FragmentManager.java:1471)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState + 1784 (FragmentManager.java:1784)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 1852 (FragmentManager.java:1852)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps + 802 (BackStackRecord.java:802)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps + 2625 (FragmentManager.java:2625)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether + 2411 (FragmentManager.java:2411)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute + 2366 (FragmentManager.java:2366)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction + 2243 (FragmentManager.java:2243)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss + 654 (BackStackRecord.java:654)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate + 168 (FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:168)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate + 1244 (ViewPager.java:1244)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate + 1092 (ViewPager.java:1092)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure + 1622 (ViewPager.java:1622)
android.view.View.measure + 22127 (View.java:22127)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins + 6604 (ViewGroup.java:6604)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure + 185 (FrameLayout.java:185)
android.view.View.measure + 22127 (View.java:22127)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins + 6604 (ViewGroup.java:6604)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure + 185 (FrameLayout.java:185)
android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure + 143 (ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
android.view.View.measure + 22127 (View.java:22127)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins + 6604 (ViewGroup.java:6604)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout + 1514 (LinearLayout.java:1514)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical + 806 (LinearLayout.java:806)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure + 685 (LinearLayout.java:685)
android.view.View.measure + 22127 (View.java:22127)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins + 6604 (ViewGroup.java:6604)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure + 185 (FrameLayout.java:185)
android.view.View.measure + 22127 (View.java:22127)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins + 6604 (ViewGroup.java:6604)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout + 1514 (LinearLayout.java:1514)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical + 806 (LinearLayout.java:806)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure + 685 (LinearLayout.java:685)
android.view.View.measure + 22127 (View.java:22127)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins + 6604 (ViewGroup.java:6604)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure + 185 (FrameLayout.java:185)
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure + 727 (DecorView.java:727)
android.view.View.measure + 22127 (View.java:22127)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure + 2482 (ViewRootImpl.java:2482)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy + 1564 (ViewRootImpl.java:1564)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals + 1821 (ViewRootImpl.java:1821)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal + 1452 (ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run + 6917 (ViewRootImpl.java:6917)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run + 1026 (Choreographer.java:1026)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks + 838 (Choreographer.java:838)

android.view.Choreographer.doFrame + 769 (Choreographer.java:769)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run + 1012 (Choreographer.java:1012)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 790 (Handler.java:790)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 99 (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop + 164 (Looper.java:164)
android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6670 (ActivityThread.java:6670)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 547 (RuntimeInit.java:547)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 821 (ZygoteInit.java:821)
```

Код внедрения зависимости и инициализации презентера:

```
         @InjectPresenter lateinit var presenter: RegistrationWithCCPresenter

         @ProvidePresenter
            fun providePresenter() = DI.componentProvider.createOrGetRegistrationComponent().createWithCCPresenter()

    object DI {

               @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
                @JvmStatic
                lateinit var componentProvider: ComponentProvider
                    private set

                fun init(applicationContext: Context) {
                    componentProvider = ComponentProvider(applicationContext)


         }
        }

        class ComponentProvider(val context: Context) {
            val appComponent: AppComponent by lazy {
                DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                    .appModule(AppModule(context))
                    .networkModule(NetworkModule())
                    .repositoryModule(RepositoryModule())
                    .build()
            }

            private var registrationComponent: RegistrationComponent? = null

            fun createOrGetRegistrationComponent(): RegistrationComponent {
                if (registrationComponent == null) {
                    registrationComponent = authComponent
                        .registrationComponentBuilder()
                        .registrationModule(RegistrationModule())
                        .build()
                }
                return registrationComponent!!
            }
        }

@RegistrationScope
@Subcomponent(modules = [(RegistrationModule::class)])
interface RegistrationComponent {

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun registrationModule(module: RegistrationModule): Builder
        fun build(): RegistrationComponent
    }
    fun createWithCCPresenter(): RegistrationWithCCPresenter
   }
```

Код где падает:

```
    regCardNumber.addTextChangedListener(createValidateWatcher(
                        editText = regCardNumber,
                        fieldType = RegisterFieldType.CardNumber
            ))

    private fun createValidateWatcher(
            editText: EditText,
            fieldType: RegisterFieldType,
            errorId: Int = R.string.reg_template_error_1,
            validator: (String) -> Boolean = { value -> value.isNotEmpty() }
    ): RegistrationFocusAndValidateWatcher =
            RegistrationFocusAndValidateWatcher(
                    editText = editText,
                    fieldType = fieldType,
                    resetData = presenter::resetFieldValue,
                    updateData = presenter::updateFieldValue,
                    showValidateResult = ::showValidateResult,
                    validator = validator,
                    errorId = errorId
            )
```

Comment: в ошибке сказано что вам нужно инициализировать переменную перед тем как ее использовать, присвойте ей значение и будет вам счастье :)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko если бы все было так просто:)

Инициализация есть, посмотрите код выше.
Проблема еще и в том, что этот же код в другом месте приложения работает нормально.